# Discord.py show who invited a user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently trying to figure out a way to know who invited a user. From the official docs, I would think that the `member` class would have an attribute showing who invited them, but it doesn't. I have a very faint idea of a possible method to get the user who invited and that would be to get all invites in the server then get the number of uses, when someone joins the server, it checks to see the invite that has gone up a use. But I don't  know if this is the most efficient method or at least the used method.

Answer (score 4):

Make a `config.json` file with the content of

```
{
    "token": "Bot token here",
    "server-id": "server id here",
    "logs-channel-id": "invite channel here"
}
```

then save that.

Make a channel called `invites` then fill in the `config.json` file. And then create a file called `bot.py` and put the contents of:

```
import asyncio
import datetime
import json
import os
import commands

client = discord.Client()
cfg = open("config.json", "r")
tmpconfig = cfg.read()
cfg.close()
config = json.loads(tmpconfig)

token = config["token"]
guild_id = config["server-id"]
logs_channel = config["logs-channel-id"]


invites = {}
last = ""

async def fetch():
 global last
 global invites
 await client.wait_until_ready()
 gld = client.get_guild(int(guild_id))
 logs = client.get_channel(int(logs_channel))
 while True:
  invs = await gld.invites()
  tmp = []
  for i in invs:
   for s in invites:
    if s[0] == i.code:
     if int(i.uses) > s[1]:
      usr = gld.get_member(int(last))
      testh = f"{usr.name} **joined**; Invited by **{i.inviter.name}** (**{str(i.uses)}** invites)"
      await logs.send(testh)
   tmp.append(tuple((i.code, i.uses)))
  invites = tmp
  await asyncio.sleep(4)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print("ready!")
 await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Activity(name = "joins", type = 2))


@client.event
async def on_member_join(meme):
 global last
 last = str(meme.id)




client.loop.create_task(fetch())
client.run(token)
```

Then open the terminal and run `python3 bot.py`. And for more help join [this](https://discordapp.com/invite/9rpBWkp).

Comment: This works perfectly fine. Some comments: if a user it's invited by right click on the profile, and send invite to server the bot dosn't regonize this. Also the support server seems to not work since there it's no way to get verified and let in.

Comment: Can you please tell me just how can i get info about who invited user? I wanted just this, not full code. But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Discord, you're never going to 100% sure who invited the user.

Using Invite, you know who created the invite.

Using on_member_join, you know who joined.

So, yes, you could have to check invites and see which invite got revoked. However, you will never know for sure who invited since anyone can paste the same invite link anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Watching the number of uses an invite has had, or for when they run out of uses and are revoked, is the only way to see how a user was invited to the server.