# When a new member joins the server in Discord.Py, bot believes multiple invites were used

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a bot that tries to find out what invite was used when a member joins the server.

When an invite is created, the bot saves the list of invites into a dictionary with the guild id as key and the list of [Invite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Invite)s as value.

When a member joins the server, the bot fetches the list of invites and compare their uses. If the invite from the newly fetched list has more uses than the last save, then we know that invite was used and we tell the server, else we do nothing

Here is my code that does that

```
class AdminCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        super().__init__(bot)
        self.list_invites = {}

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_invite_create(self, invite: Invite):
        self.list_invites[str(invite.guild.id)] = await invite.guild.invites()
        announce_channel = ANNOUNCE_CHANNEL_ID
        await announce_channel.send(f"{invite.inviter.mention} created an invite for channel "
                                    f"{invite.channel.mention} with {invite.max_uses} max uses and "
                                    f"a lifetime of {invite.max_age}")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    @has_admin_role()
    async def on_member_join(self, member: Member):
        guild = member.guild
        announce_channel = ANNOUNCE_CHANNEL_ID
        new_invites = await member.guild.invites()
        for old, new in zip(self.list_invites[str(guild.id)], new_invites):
            if old.uses < new.uses:
                await announce_channel.send(
                    f"{member.mention} a été invité par {new.inviter.mention} ({new.uses} invitations)")
        self.list_invites[str(guild.id)] = new_invites
```

I know I can add a `break` in the for once the invite was found but I am not sure that the first time the condition is satisfied is the correct invite so I go through them all.

The problem is that apparently, when only one person joins the server, the bot believes it was invited through a lot of invites

[image: behaviour screenshot]

While obviously this cannot happen, and as you can see the number of uses of the invite only raised for one inviter

My theory is that either `await invite.guild.invites()` returned a cached list instead of the actual list, or that maybe two calls to `await invite.guild.invites()` give lists in a different order.

What do you think ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: It is actually returning you the current active invites.

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav yes, it is what I want, when a member joins, I simply compare the old save of the invites versus the new one (after 1 member joined), so I should find only 1 invite for which the number of used increased

Comment: Oh! I need some time for that. Let me dig through some docs and I'll get back to this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar answer.

I am posting the link here. If you feel it is difficult to understand, just tell me and I will simplify the code and then explain it to you.

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60974911/14141072

Thank You! :D

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, I do not want the track the number of invites of one user, but I want to see who invited the new comer by comparing the number of uses

Comment: I updated the link with another answer. Use it and I think that'll help.